# For an Arduino nano, how do I use a keyboard input to control when serial.print() occurs?

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to use an Arduino nano with a humidity sensor and using the serial monitor to collect the data on my computer. When I'm done with my test, I want it to stop printing data to the serial monitor so I can copy and paste the data to a spreadsheet. I think there's a way to do this by pressing space bar and I can have it stop printing, but i'm not sure how. Thanks in advance

I can get the data to print, but I do not know how to tell it to stop.

Comment: If you want to read the serial console, you can try [Serial.read()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/read/)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution: Disconnect either by unplugging or by using another terminal software like Hterm, which allows to close the serial connection or even directly write to files.

Usually you'll have a start/stop command that you send to your device from the PC or you process a hardware button to achieve the same.

Arduinos Serial Monitor is very simple and very limited in functionality.